# How to check http-redirect samlresponse uri request

Tags: c#, saml-2.0

I am getting the xml, signature and signature-algoirthm seperate in a http-get.
so, How do I approach this to validate the signature?

currently my code is this:

```
public void CheckSignature(string response, string sig, string sigalg, byte[] cert) 
{
    Log("loading cert");
    X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);

    bool result = false;

    /* response, sigalg and sig are url-decoded or not, doesn't matter :( */
    Log("first variant");
    var signedString = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SAMLResponse={0}&SigAlg={1}", response, sigalg);
    result = DoCheck(signedString, sigalg, sig, cert2);

    Log("2nd variant");
    signedString = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SAMLResponse={0}", response);
    result = DoCheck(signedString, sigalg, sig, cert2);


    Log("3rd variant");
    signedString = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", response);
    result = DoCheck(signedString, sigalg, sig, cert2); 
}

private bool DoCheck(string signedString, string sigalg, string sig, X509Certificate2 cert2) 
{
    try {
        var sigDescription = (SignatureDescription)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(sigalg);
        var hashAlg = sigDescription.CreateDigest();
        //why is this needed?
        hashAlg.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signedString));

        var signature = Convert.FromBase64String(sig);

        Log("trying to verify::" +  signedString + Environment.NewLine);

        X509AsymmetricSecurityKey key = new X509AsymmetricSecurityKey(cert2);
        AsymmetricAlgorithm asym_alg = key.GetAsymmetricAlgorithm(sigalg, false);
        AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter def = sigDescription.CreateDeformatter(asym_alg);


        bool result = false;
        result = def.VerifySignature(hashAlg, signature);
        //sadly always false.
        Log("woop woop:" + result);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Log(ex.Message);
        Log(ex.StackTrace);
    }
    return false;
}
```

but for now, whatever I do, the result is always false.
based on https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/master/Kentor.AuthServices/WebSSO/Saml2RedirectBinding.cs

Answer (score 0):

If you get a query string on the form `SAMLResponse=....SigAlg=...Signature=...` (first param can also be `SAMLRequest`) you are getting a message using the SAML2 HTTP Redirect binding. Please see the [SAML2 Specification](https://wiki.oasis-open.org/security/FrontPage#SAMLV2.0Standard) for a description of how it works. Specifically you should read the binding specification.

Or if you want to save yourself a lot of work, find an existing SAML2 implementation to use instead. There are several open source implementations for C# available.

Comment: Well, I understand how it works in the specs.. but the open source implementation are not suitable/crappy documented for my specific purposes.

Comment: If you have specific purposes, why don't you include those purposes in the question? That can help in getting a better response.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the vagueness. Added my current code. I am not sure If i am able to get the httprequestdata as your code btw..

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I found it out myself.
It really is the issue of the rawrequest parameters.
(My code already parsed it, but then it fails anyhow)

```
// Can't use the query string params as found in HttpReqeustData
// because they are already unescaped and we need the exact format
// of the original data.
        var rawQueryStringParams = request.Url.Query.TrimStart('?')
            .Split('&')
            .Select(qp => qp.Split('='))
            .ToDictionary(kv => kv[0], kv => kv[1]);
```